# Using thymeleaf, how can I pass a date from an input as a request param in a link in the same template?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm building a support page that will download a report between two input dates, and I need some help figuring out how to pass those dates to get downloaded.

I've tried a method I saw on here, but it doesn't update the date in the link when the date is changed in the input.

My controller looks like:

```
    @Controller
    public class SupportController {
      @GetMapping("/reports")
      public void getReports(Model model) {

         DateInputs inputs = new DateInputs();
         //Setting initial values
         inputs.setStart(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1));
         inputs.setEnd(LocalDate.now());
         model.addAttribute("inputs", inputs);
       }

      @ResponseBody
      @GetMapping("/reporting/download")
      public void downloadReports(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam String start, 
      @RequestParam String end) {

         reportService.exportReport(response, start, end);
       }
    }
```

The Inputs class:

```
@Data
Public class DateInputs {
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private LocalDate start;

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private LocalDate end;
}
```

And my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://wwww.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="date" th:value="${inputs.start}" th:field="${inputs.start}" />
    <input type="date" th:value="${inputs.end}" th:field="${inputs.end}" />
  </div>

<a th:href="@{|/reports/download?start=${inputs.start}&end=${inputs.end}|}">
  <h3 th:text="|Download|"></h3>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know how I can go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try using `onChange` event in your input?

Comment: as you have to use onChange event when you change your date input else it won't work

Comment: Thymeleaf runs on the server. So updates to the date input in the browser do not reflect in Thymeleaf. You need to either do a post via a form with the date values, or use JavaScript to update the URL of the link on the client side.